# how do i generate a line break inside a loop in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a react component that i need to break into lines. It generates 4-5 boxes of li's in a looped return i'm guessing. What I want to do is have 2 boxes on top, and then 3 below it. So if there are 4 boxes, they will be stack 2x2 on top of each other. If there are 5, 2 on top, 3 on the bottom.

So the question is, how do i generate a line break in a looped return in react?

code:

```
import React from 'react'
import classnames from 'classnames'

export default class Tile extends React.Component {
 constructor( props ) {
  super( props )
}

componentWillAppear( done ) {
// let rotateZ = `rotateZ( ${ ~~( ( Math.random() * -20 ) + 
Math.random() * 40 ) }deg )`
// let rotateX = `rotateX( ${ ~~( Math.random() * 80 ) }deg )`
// let scale = `scale( ${ .65 + Math.random() * .25 } )`
// let initialTransform = {
//   transform: `${ rotateZ } ${ rotateX } ${ scale }`
// }
// this.refs.container.style.transform = `${ rotateZ } ${ rotateX } ${ 
scale }`

this.refs.container.classList.add( 'Tile--isAppearing' )
done()
}

componentDidAppear() {
setTimeout( () => {
  // set visible and clear jitter
  this.refs.container.classList.remove( 'Tile--isAppearing' )
  this.refs.container.style.transform= ''
}, Math.random() * ( this.props.number * 250 ) )
}

onClick = event => {
const { id, value } = this.props
this.props.onClick( id, value )
}

render() {
// Add matrix jitter

let classes = classnames({
  'Tile': true,
  'Tile--isSelected': this.props.selected
})

return (

  <li ref="container" className={ classes } onClick={ this.onClick }>
    <span className="Tile-content">{ this.props.text }</span>
  </li>

)
  }
}
```

Second set of code requested:

```
render() {
let tiles = this.props.slide.answers
  .map( ( answer, index ) => {
    let id = 'answer' + index
    return <Tile
      key={ id }
      id={ id }
      value={ answer.value }
      text={ answer.text }
      selected={ this.selected.has( id ) }
      onClick={ this.onTileClick }
    />
  })

 let buttonClasses = classnames( 'Btn', 'Btn--isOrange', 'Btn--
 isContinue', {
  'u-transparent': !this.state.complete
})

   return (
  <div ref="main" className="js-main State">
    <p className="Question-Body">
      { this.props.slide.body }
    </p>
    <TransitionGroup { ...transitionProps } >
      { tiles }
    </TransitionGroup>
    <button ref="continue" className={ buttonClasses } onClick={ 
  this.onContinue }>{ this.props.slide.continue }</button>
  </div>
  )
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're using right now?

Comment: could you please show some code ?

Comment: code added. im no react master, so i have little knowledge as to what the above means.

Comment: We need the code for the parent component, the one that renders instances of `<Tile />`.

Comment: I have no idea what you are referring to.

Comment: Assuming the file you posted is called `tile.js`, one of your other files is going to have `import Tile from 'tile';` at the top. We need to see the `render()` method of this other file.

Comment: Surely none of that should matter? The react code will generate 4 or 5 tiles depending on the page. All i want to do is add a break after the second tile, so it displays 2 on top, 3 on the bottom. Or 2x2.

Comment: "None of that should matter"...? Are you sure...? You have shown code that renders *a single tile*. We need the code that renders *four* or *five* of them.

Comment: @JoshWinters If you want a certain pattern when these boxes are generated, then `render()` must be important.

Comment: The above code is what i assume was requested, based on where i was directed to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually insert the line break:

```
let tiles = this.props.slide.answers
  .map( ( answer, index ) => {
    let id = 'answer' + index
    let tile = <Tile
      key={ id }
      id={ id }
      value={ answer.value }
      text={ answer.text }
      selected={ this.selected.has( id ) }
      onClick={ this.onTileClick }
    />
    return index == 1 ? [tile, <br/>] : tile;
  })
```

This will turn `[tile, tile, tile, tile]` into `[tile, [tile, <br/>], tile, tile]`

Comment: This was an awesome answer, thank you very much. worked like a charm. You guys are awesome, much love.