# How to add a line break during the process of rendering a component while using a map function in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, loops, mapping, rendering

Goal: Render the component using `map function` and `add a line break` for `every after the 5th column component is rendered` and so on for the following rows formed.

Problem: I am unsure on how to add a line break within the mapping functionality. I got confused on what to manipulate when it comes to adding a line break.

The content of the component is read from a `data.jsx` file containing an object with several properties that have their own values.

Appearance issue:
[image: appearance issue]

Goal appearance: [image: goal appearance]

Source code for rendering the component using map functionality (`Main.jsx`):

```
import React from "react";
import Product from "./Product";


export default function Main(props){
  const { products, onAdd } = props;
    return (
      <main className="block col-2">
        <h2>Products</h2>
        <div className="row">
          {products.map((product) => (
            <Product key={product.id} product={product} onAdd={onAdd} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </main>
    );
}
```

Source code for `data.jsx`:

```
const data = {
  products: [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "MacBook",
      price: 1400,
      image: "https://picsum.photos/id/180/2400/1600"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Old Car",
      price: 2400,
      image: "https://picsum.photos/id/111/4400/2656"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "W Shoes",
      price: 1000,
      image: "https://picsum.photos/id/21/3008/2008"
    },

    {
      id: "4",
      name: "W Shoes 2",
      price: 1200,
      image: "https://picsum.photos/id/21/3008/2008"
    },

    {
      id: "5",
      name: "W Shoes 3",
      price: 1300,
      image: "https://picsum.photos/id/21/3008/2008"
    },

    {
      id: "6",
      name: "W Shoes 3",
      price: 1300,
      image: "https://picsum.photos/id/21/3008/2008"
    },

    {
      id: "7",
      name: "W Shoes 3",
      price: 1300,
      image: "https://picsum.photos/id/21/3008/2008"
    },

    {
      id: "8",
      name: "W Shoes 3",
      price: 1300,
      image: "https://picsum.photos/id/21/3008/2008"
    }
  ]
};
export default data;
```

Full functioning App in CodeSandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/renderbuttonsnewlinefixing-cherry-h0br4o-forked-88d2q7?file=/src/components/Main.jsx

Similar Stack question: [how do i generate a line break inside a loop in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44311109/how-do-i-generate-a-line-break-inside-a-loop-in-react)

(But I am not sure how to exactly implement this way from this question since it did not functioned well for me)

Your responses would indeed help me a lot since I am currently learning the ropes of React fundamentals when it comes to mapping and rendering components. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you clarify whether the solution should always linebreak after each fifth item? Or does it need to be responsive-friendly also?

Comment: The solution should always line break after each fifth item, it can also be responsive-friendly too but I haven't fully implemented the responsive aspects yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you? I'm assuming you just need a line break, not a literal `<br />`.

```
import React from "react";
import Product from "./Product";

export default function Main(props) {
  const { products, onAdd } = props;

  return (
    <main className="block col-2">
      <h2>Products</h2>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "grid",
          gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(5, 1fr)"
        }}
      >
        {products.length &&
          products.map((product) => (
            <Product key={product.id} product={product} onAdd={onAdd} />
          ))}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Change `1fr` in this line `gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(5, 1fr)"` to whatever width you want for each product. `1fr` means that the space is divided equally for each product.

[image: Edit renderButtonsNewLineFixing-cherry-h0br4o (forked)]

Comment: I see, using grid as a style for the code's CSS aspects indeed worked like a charm! I should have covered the rendered components inside a "container-like" entity, such as the div which you applied grid upon it as a style. My version lacked any kind of divs/containers since it was only directly rendered plainly through a map function.

Comment: Thank you very much for this one @nullptr, you exactly solved my code issue which helped me a lot in gaining the logic for rendering the components on a specific style such as using grid. Again, thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootstrap, you can take advantage of the flexbox styling and make use of the flex-wrap property, then adjust your max-width until you can see only 5 items are rendered in every row.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap" style={{ maxWidth: YOUR_MAX_WIDTH_HERE }}>
  {products.map((product) => (
        <Product key={product.id} product={product} onAdd={onAdd} />
   ))}
</div>
```

Comment: Oh nice, that's a good react dependency CSS framework to use though, good suggestion.
But when I applied it to my code in the Main.jsx , it rendered in a weird manner where it automatically added a line break every after the rendered component.

Updated codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/productitemsdisplayfixing-cherry-h0br4o-forked-nvu3d0?file=/src/components/Main.jsx

(Good to see a fellow kababayan Filipino React developer here at Stack^_^)

Comment: Hoping you may have another well response in regards to this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly achieve this using a grid system if you go for React Bootstrap or AntD. https://ant.design/components/grid/

Here you go, Just had to do some conditional styling to get it to work Horizontally :)

```
const displayProducts = (products, cols = 5) => {
  let isFirstComp = true;
  return products.map((product, i) => {
    isFirstComp = i % cols === 0 && i !== 0 ? true : false;

    return (
      <div key={i}>
        <Product product={product} isFirstComp={isFirstComp} />
      </div>
    );
  });
};

const Product = ({ isFirstComp, product }) => {
  console.log(isFirstComp);
  return (
    <div>
      {isFirstComp ? (
        <div>
          <div
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "green",
              width: 20,
              margin: "10px 20px",
              float: "left",
              clear: isFirstComp ? "both" : "none",
              color: "white",
              padding: 20,
            }}
          >
            {product}
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "green",
            width: 20,
            margin: "10px 20px",
            float: isFirstComp ? "none" : "left",
            clear: isFirstComp ? "both" : "none",
            color: "white",
            padding: 20,
          }}
        >
          {product}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Just pass the number of Columns you need as a param like this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great conditional method, but I think you are almost there. Its just that the rendering here displays it vertically rather than horizontally.

Comment: I updated my question picture so you can see the goal appearance clearly @iWiiCK

Comment: I edited my answer so that it can be used Horizontally. Cheers :) @RalphHenry

Comment: Nice nice!!! This should also be useful in terms of implementing the alignment of the rendered components. Thank you very much @iWiiCK

Answer (score 0):

Try this one plz

```
  {products.length && products.map((product, index) => 
        <>
              <Product key={product.id} product={product} onAdd={onAdd} />
              {products.length > index && <br/>}
        </>
   )}
```

Comment: Hello @HacıCelalAygar, currently it still doesn't work since it continuosly renders the component on one row only and still it doesn't give out a line break for every 5th column component.

I am not sure where is the condition here where the 5th column component will give out a line break.

Comment: I edit code , can you try this code

Comment: Nope, doesn't work, still it renders on one row continuously and ruins the overall look of the page.

Comment: Hoping you may have another well response in regards to this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent{
  display:flex;
 flex-direction:row;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 gap:12px;
}
```

add this style on your parent wrapper.